# Unable to extract value_type from template

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am attempting to extract the `value_type` from a container using the following code.

```
//CustomTraits.h
template<typename C, typename = void> 
struct has_push_back : std::false_type {};

template<typename C>
struct has_push_back<C, std::void_t<  decltype(std::declval<C>())::value_type > > :
  std::true_type {};
```

It is invoked like so

```
//MessaDecoder.h
template <typename Container, 
  typename = std::enable_if_t<has_push_back<Container>::value>
>
class MessageDecoder{/*Class Def...*/};

//Server.h
using buffer_t = std::deque<std::tuple<std::string, uint64_t>>;
std::shared_ptr<MessageHelper::MessageDecoder<buffer_t>> _decoder_ptr;
```

I have tried a significant number of variations in attempting to get this code to compile. I have tested that `value_type` is valid by extracting this as a template parameter in `MessageDecoder.h` with `Container::value_type` and it does compile. However, doing the same and what I have above in `CustomTraits.h` fails to correctly trigger the specialized template and I am wondering why and how to fix it. Here are some errors I am getting.

```
Error   C3203   'MessageDecoder': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type  

Error   C2938   'enable_if_t<false,void>' : Failed to specialize alias template
```

I am using VS2017 C++ 17 the latest update.

Comment: Why `decltype(std::declval<C>())::value_type` instead of `C::value_type` (which would have to be `typename C::value_type`)?

Comment: OT `has_push_back` seems like a misleading name.

Comment: `template<typename C>
struct has_push_back<C, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<C>().push_back(  std::declval<typename C::value_type>()))>> :
  std::true_type {};`

This is the full code I just omitted that for brevity and since the other part was working correctly I wanted to hone into why what I had wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
decltype(std::declval<C>())::value_type
```

To

```
typename C::value_type
```

`declval` gives you an rvalue reference, you can't pull members off of reference types (and that dance is unnecessary since you just want the type, which you have: `C`). And you're missing `typename`.

Comment: Why does it need `typename` prefixed before it to work? (NVM) it s a dependent type.

Comment: Because the template is parsed before instantiation so the compiler has to be told that a particular name is a type rather than a member (variable or function), just like if you have a member template you have to use the template keyword a(s in typename foo::template bar<T>::qux).